# 0.0.0.0 refused to connect

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I want to deploy simple static website as Non-Root user with Docker. I have created Docker file with below content:

```
FROM nginx:stable

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html


RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R 1000:1000 /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R 1000:1000 /var/cache/nginx

USER 1000

VOLUME /var/www

EXPOSE 8086
```

File Structure

- dashboard    assets    src
      dashboard.html
      login.html    Docker file    site.conf    nginx.conf

I build Docker with below command:

```
docker build -t ubdashboard:v4
```

Running with below command

```
docker run -d -p 8086:80 ubdashboard:v4
```

I can see below container is running:

```
edureka@edureka:~/dashboard$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
a74332a5f568        ubdashboard:v4      "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        8086/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp   flamboyant_jang
```

But when I try to access 0.0.0.0:8086 or 0.0.0.0:80 , below message in Google chrome:
This site can’t be reached

The web page at http://0.0.0.0:8086/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Please guide here.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 does not actually exist, it is used to signal the system that the service is willing to accept connections from all interfaces. Use any actual IP of your system to connect to it in your browser.

Comment: You cannot access 0.0.0.0 as it is an invalid IP for a computer to have. You should use 172.0.0.1 to access the web server. NgNinx listens on 0.0.0.0 which means that it accepts connections from all network adapters in the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Exploding the commment from Gerben Jongerius:

```
8086/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp
```

means that the port 80/tcp on the container is mapped to the port 8086 on ALL the ips of your host (the machine where docekr is running).

To access the nginx server you can open http://127.0.0.1:8086 on your host.

Comment: Hi @Simonluca Landi and @ Gerben Jongerius I tried with  http://127.0.0.1:8086 but its giving below message : The web page at http://127.0.0.1:8086/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED .  I tried with localhost:8086 , it's giving same message

Comment: Hi Simonluca,  Thank you for mentioning this command. From logs I saw file login.html was not present in Image. I made mistake in Dockefile while copying it. I fixed it now and able to access the pages